# no match for operator << in out using operator overloading c++

Tags: c++

I'm getting these errors when trying to use operator overloading. The problem is these files were given to me by my instructor and I know they are correct, yet when I am trying to use them I'm getting errors that shouldn't be happening. I also cannot modify these files so maybe it's my makefile or how I call it but I cannot figure it out.

Node.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Node&)’:

Node.cpp:88: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘out << "Node [word="’

Node.cpp:86: note: candidates are: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Node&)

Node.cpp:89: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘out << ((const Node*)inNode)->Node::GetFrequency()’

Node.cpp:86: note: candidates are: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Node&)

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Node &inNode)
{
  out << "Node [word=" << inNode.GetWord() << ", frequency=";       //line 88
  out << inNode.GetFrequency() << "]" ;
  return out;
}
```

edit: I have provided GetFrquency and GetWord, and yes I'm certain they are correct as I cannot modify these files and other people have succeeded in not modifying the files.

```
//Return the int for frequency
int Node::GetFrequency() const
{
  return m_frequency;
}


//Return the string for the word
string Node::GetWord() const
{
  return m_word;
}
```

Node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include "Util.h" // For some string functions

using namespace std;

class Node{

 public:

  Node();
  Node(string inWord, int frequency);
  ~Node();
  string GetWord() const;
  int GetFrequency() const;
  void IncrementFrequency();
  bool operator<(const Node &RHS) const;
  bool operator==(const Node &RHS);
  Node operator=(const Node &RHS);
  bool operator%(const Node& RHS) const;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Node &inNode);
 private:
  std::string m_word; // The word
  int m_frequency;    // How often the word has appeared.
};

#endif
```

Node.cpp

```
#include "Node.h"

using namespace std;

//No parameter constructor for containers
Node::Node(){}


//Full constructor
Node::Node(string inWord, int frequency) : m_word(inWord),
                                           m_frequency(frequency){}


//Destructor
Node::~Node(){}


//Compares this to RHS and returns true if the word is less than
bool Node::operator<(const Node& RHS) const
{
  return (this->m_word < RHS.m_word);
}


//Compares this to RHS and returns true if the words are identical
bool Node::operator==(const Node& RHS)
{
  return (this->m_word == RHS.m_word);
}


//Deep copy
Node Node::operator=(const Node& RHS)
{
  //Be sure we aren't copying over the node
  if( this != &RHS )
    {
      this->m_word = RHS.m_word;
      this->m_frequency = RHS.m_frequency;
    }
  return *this;
}


//Check to see if we have a substring
bool Node::operator%(const Node& RHS) const
{
  //We want to ignore case on this check
  string text = this->GetWord();
  text = Util::Lower(text);

  string compared = RHS.GetWord();
  compared = Util::Lower(compared);

  // If the substring is longer it really isn't a substring
  if (text.length() > compared.length()) {return false;}
  //Check each character of the substring against the compared string
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
    if (text[i] != compared[i]){
      //One miss is all it takes to not have a match
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}


//Increment the frequency
void Node::IncrementFrequency()
{
  m_frequency++;
}


//Formatted output
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Node &inNode)
{
  out << "Node [word=" << inNode.GetWord() << ", frequency=";
  out << inNode.GetFrequency() << "]" ;
  return out;
}


//Return the int for frequency
int Node::GetFrequency() const
{
  return m_frequency;
}


//Return the string for the word
string Node::GetWord() const
{
  return m_word;
}
```

Comment: Did you provide a forward (friend) declaration for this operator overload also?

Comment: _"I know they are correct, yet when I am trying to use them I'm getting errors that shouldn't be happening."_ Then obviously they're _not_ correct...

Comment: Show us your testcase. Headers. Types. It's all important.

Comment: Post the full source code.

Comment: That's all the Node.h and Node.cpp source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `#include <ostream>`.  I strongly suspect your header files are including just `<iosfwd>`, which declares the `std::ostream` type but not its related `operator<<` members or functions.

Comment: Actually when I include it into the Node.cpp file it works, just not when I include it into the other file oddly.

Comment: Is there anyway to fix it so it works into the file I'm including